# Apostrophe won't let me delete items

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a CMS where I can create/delete items/menus/pages etc. I have a onclick jquery script that deletes something once you click an icon. Problem I am having is that when I have a page/menu/item with an apostrophe within its name, I am unable to delete it.

Here is snippets of my code:

jquery:

```
function confirmDeleteMenuItem(mi_id, mi_name) {
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the menu item \''+mi_name+'\'?\nNote: All sub-items will also be deleted.')) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType:  'json',
        url: cmsRelPath+'/app/menus/ajax_delete_menu_item.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            mi_id: mi_id
        },
```

php:

```
$cell .= '<img src="'.$cms_settings["cms_relative_dir"].'/images/icon_delete.png" width="30" height="30" border="0" alt="delete" title="Click to delete item." class="cursorPointer" onclick="confirmDeleteMenuItem('.$row->mi_id.',\''.html_entities($row->mi_name).'\');" />';
```

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double quotes in `confirm()`:

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the menu item "'+mi_name+'"?\nNote: All sub-items will also be deleted.')) {
/* ............ */
```

and PHP:

```
$cell .= '<img src="'.$cms_settings["cms_relative_dir"].'/images/icon_delete.png" width="30" height="30" border="0" alt="delete" title="Click to delete item." class="cursorPointer" onclick="confirmDeleteMenuItem('.$row->mi_id.',\''.html_entities(str_replace("'", "\'", $row->mi_name)).'\');" />';
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this but I am still unable to delete.

Comment: Aaaa ... you have an apostrophe in your `mi_name`, let me edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the apostrophe with \ symbol, like `\'`.